# Openshift/Kubernates kube dns best practise (ndots = 5)

Tags: networking, kubernetes, dns, openshift, kube-dns

I have been using Openshift/Kubernates for some time and this has been the understanding.
For service to service communication

- use DNS name of `${service-name}` if they are under the same namespace
- use DNS name of `${service-name}.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local` if they are from different namespaces (network is joined)

Recently i was introduced with the topic of "we should add a dot after the svc.cluster.local to make it FQDN, for better DNS lookup speed". Done some testing and indeed with lookup is much faster with the dot. (~100ms without dot, 10ms with dot)

After some research, it was caused by the default dns setting from the kubernates

```
sh-4.2$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
search ${namespace}.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
nameserver X.X.X.X
options ndots:5
```

the ndots = 5 will perform a local search (sequential) if the dns name does not contain 5 dots.
In the case of `${service-name}.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local`, the local search will be as such

1. `${service-name}.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local` + `${namespace}.svc.cluster.local` // FAILED LOOKUP
2. `${service-name}.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local` + `svc.cluster.local` // FAILED LOOKUP
3. `${service-name}.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local` + `cluster.local` // FAILED LOOKUP
4. `${service-name}.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local` // SUCCESS LOOKUP

And for `${service-name}.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local.`, the local search will be as such

1. `${service-name}.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local` // SUCCESS LOOKUP

References

1. [link](https://pracucci.com/kubernetes-dns-resolution-ndots-options-and-why-it-may-affect-application-performances.html)
2. [how to debug](https://rcarrata.com/openshift/dns-deep-dive-in-openshift/)

Questions:

1. Since the `ndots = 5` is the default setting for kubernetes, why `${service-name}.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local.` is not documented on the official side ?
2. Should we change all service call to `${service-name}.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local.` ? any potential downsides ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the latest document [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns), it states that that we should use `${service}.${namespace}` to call a service from different namespace and expect to resolve on the second attempt

Answer (score 1):

> Since the `ndots = 5` is the default setting for kubernetes, why
> `${service-name}.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local.` is not documented on
> the official side ?

Well, it's a really good question. I searched through the official docs and it looks like this is not a documented feature. For this reason much better place for posting your doubts and also request for documentation improvement is the official **GitHub** site of [Kubernetes DNS](https://github.com/kubernetes/dns).

> Should we change all service call to
> `${service-name}.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local.` ? any potential
> downsides ?

If it works well for you and definitely increases the performance, I would say *- Why not ?* I can't see any potential downsides here. By adding the last dot you're simply omitting those first 3 lookups that are doomed to failure anyway if you use `Service` domain name in a form of `${service-name}.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local`

Inferring from lookup process you described and your tests, I guess if you use only `${service-name}` (of course only within the same `namespace`), dns lookup should be also much faster and closer to those `10ms` you observed when using `${namespace}.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local.` as then it is matched in the very first iteration.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I indeed posted the question on the kubernates repo. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/93824#issuecomment-684888550
Apparently they are still looking at the right way to resolve it

Comment: in short this is probably i would summarize/recommend
- for outbound call, use FQDN
- for same ns call, use ${service-name}
- for different service name, use FQDN as well